# How to make flutter showDialog, AlertDialog barrier color gradient

Tags: flutter, dart

here is an example

[image]

you can see the barrier color as gradient, and in flutter there is only one parameter for `showDialog` widget named `barrierColor`.

is there any way to set the barrierColor gradient?

here is the given picture's `showDialog` code

```
showDialog(
                barrierColor: AppColor.pink.withAlpha(200),
                context: context,
                builder: (BuildContext context) {
                  return Dialog(
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
                    ),
                    child: Container(
                      height: 300,
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                          Row(
                            children: [
                              Text(
                                option,
                                style: const TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 18,
                                    color: Colors.black,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                         const SizedBox(height: 8),
                          const TextField(
                            cursorColor: Colors.black,
                            textInputAction: TextInputAction.newline,
                             maxLines: null,
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                              hintText: 'Tell us...',
                              border: InputBorder.none,
                            ),
                          ),
                          const Spacer(),
                          Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                            children: [
                              TextButton(
                                onPressed: () {
                                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                },
                                child: const Text(
                                  'Cancel',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.black,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              TextButton(
                                onPressed: () {
                                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                },
                                child: const Text(
                                  'Save',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.black,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              );
```

here is the code, i want to achieve the barrier color as gradient color,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Container` Widget's `decoration` property has gradient parameter in it. So you can wrap your `AlertDialog` Widget with `Container` Widget and use gradient property.

**NOTE : - Whichever color you give, add opacity to it or else the background won't be visible because by default it has solid color.**

Sample Code : -

```
Container(
decoration: BoxDecoration(
  gradient: LinearGradient(
      begin: Alignment.topCenter,
      end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
      colors: [
    const Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 36, 226).withOpacity(0.2),
    const Color.fromARGB(255, 39, 205, 255).withOpacity(0.2)
              ]
            )
        )
    )
 ),
```

Full Code : -

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('AlertDialog Sample')),
        body: const Center(
          child: DialogExample(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class DialogExample extends StatelessWidget {
  const DialogExample({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextButton(
      onPressed: () => showDialog<String>(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) => Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              gradient: LinearGradient(
                  begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                  end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                  colors: [
                const Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 36, 226).withOpacity(0.2),
                const Color.fromARGB(255, 39, 205, 255).withOpacity(0.2)
              ])),
          child: AlertDialog(
            title: const Text('AlertDialog Title'),
            content: const Text('AlertDialog description'),
            actions: <Widget>[
              TextButton(
                onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context, 'Cancel'),
                child: const Text('Cancel'),
              ),
              TextButton(
                onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context, 'OK'),
                child: const Text('OK'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      child: const Text('Show Dialog'),
    );
  }
}
```

Output : -

[image]